# Format String Value Precision not working

Tags: c#, string-formatting, precision

I have the following code that I think should format the string to have four decimal places.
(The intent is for a value of 3.59, add trailing zeros so the string value becomes 3.5900)

```
string   PreFC = string.Format(dr.Cells["Price"].Value.ToString(),"{0:n4}");
                       // PreFC = (dr.Cells["Price"].Value.ToString());

                        StringBuilder FC = new StringBuilder(PreFC);
                        MessageBox.Show(PreFC);
```

This doesn't work. The value it gives me is 3.59 instead of 3.5900. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: the `.ToString()` already convers the value to string so no further formatting is available.

Comment: That actually makes sense. Thanks @ja72!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **misplaced format** and value it should be:

```
string   PreFC = string.Format("{0:n4}", dr.Cells["Price"].Value);
                            //Format should be first
```

Don't call `ToString` on Value, You will not get the numeric format to work on string values. Instead just pass `dr.Cells["Price"].Value`, since `string.Format` accepts `object` type parameter

Comment: Why cast or convert?  String.Format expects object arguments.

Comment: I got a invalid cast exception when trying the first line.

The second one worked perfectly! Thank You soo much!

Answer (score 2):

See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For "Precision specifier" use "f"

```
string PreFC = ((double)dr.Cells["Price"].Value).ToString("f");
```

Comment: You need to change the order of the arguments to `string.Format()`.

Comment: @lomed, isn't `Value` of an `Object` type and as such supports only parameterless `ToString()`?